# Azure Search stored=false

Tags: search, solr, azure-cognitive-search

Solr (among others) permits fields to be *indexed*, but not *stored*. Unless I’ve missed something in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/rest/api/searchservice/Create-Index), Azure Search doesn’t appear to support this option.

It does have an attribute called *retrievable*, but it states

> Currently, selecting this attribute does not cause a measurable increase in index storage requirements.

This suggests to me that Azure Search is storing everything anyway, and perhaps enabling toggling of this behaviour in-place?

My question is, **how can I define a field in an equivalent way to stored=false in Azure Search**?

Comment: While I'm not familiar with Azure and can't say for sure if this is supported, my guess is that they make all fields stored and non-changable to be able to properly support partial updates through their `merge` syntax for documents without people magically losing content.

Comment: Yeah I think you’re right @MatsLindh. This is likely a deal-breaker for me to use Azure Search because I don’t need to store any fields, only index them and retrieve IDs. I’ll have an enormous index, 90% of the size of which will be unused!!

Answer (score 1):

As MatsLindh said, in Azure Search, **an index is a persistent store** of documents and other constructs used for filtered and full text search on an Azure Search service. So, you **could not define a field to store=false**.

According to that you have a large index, one of the simplest mechanisms is to **submit multiple documents or records in a single request**.

> Note: To keep document size down, remember to exclude non-queryable data from the request. Images and other binary data are not directly searchable and shouldn't be stored in the index. To integrate non-queryable data into search results, you should define a non-searchable field that stores a URL reference to the resource.

For more details about indexing large data sets in Azure Search, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-large-index).

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have a reference for the statement that you cannot define a field to store=false? The index size is not really a problem of ingestion, although that will certainly be a factor, more it’s just the sheer index size if all searchable parts of documents must be persisted as documents and not just in the search tree structure.